# How to shutdown Cats Effect Runtime

Tags: scala, scala-cats, cats-effect

Is there a way to shutdown the cats effect runtime from within an application, similar to `System.exit(0)`?

There is a `shutdown` method on `IORuntime` but it is not documented and it behaves weirdly when I call it on `IORuntime.global`: it does not shut the application down, it just seems to hang it. Also accessing `runtime` on my `IOApp` just throws a `NullPointerException` so I cannot use that. What I want to do is: from within my application a want to make the complete runtime shutdown cleanly, i.e. cancelling the main fiber and running all finalisers. I know I can implement such a shutdown-hook myself, but I was wondering if that is already supported somehow by cats effect, which is what the existence of these methods suggest.

Comment: I guess the cannonical answer would be something like: build your app with Resource and Fibers, at some place inside Resources put something which awaits Signal before exiting Resource .use. Then closing resources and exiting `main` would handle shutdown properly - when you need to exit, you run this Signal. Basically, you have to design your whole architecture to handle shutdown gracefully, with no global hacks.

Comment: Yes, the right way to cleanly shutdown a **CE** app, is using some form of kill switch. You may ask for more details in the **Discord** server: https://discord.gg/rtzPcX9p

Comment: Ok i get that, I know how to implement that, I just wanted to know if there is a global kill switch, totally fine if there isn't. I still wonder what the usecase `shutdown` function on IORuntime is supposed to be...

Comment: From what I see `IORuntime` is not supposed to be called by you, it's something that runtime passes around for its own convenience, that's why it's not documented.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like (pseudocode)

```
object MyApp extends IOApp.Simple {
  def run =
    Deferred[IO].flatMap { shutdown =>
      val app = buildMyAppResource(shutdown)
      IO.race(shutdown.get, app.useForever)
    }
}
```

Inside your app code, it can call `shutdown.complete(())`. The `IO.race` will run both fibers until one completes, then cancel the other. The `useForever` means your app won't close on its own, and the `shutdown.get` will wait until it's completed. So when your app calls `shutdown.complete`, the `app` resource will be interrupted and cancelled, letting the program exit after doing a clean resource release